# A question on a body moving up a ramp

Tags: kinematics, energy-conservation, homework-and-exercises

Let us consider a ramp of vertical height $h$ and an angle $x$. A body at the bottom of the ramp is given a velocity $v$ such that it moves up the ramp length and continues as a body that is vertically projected at angle $x$ from a height $h$.

Now the normal force shouldn't do any work since it is perpendicular to displacement of the body) so if I wish to calculate maximum height, I can ignore the ramp altogether and conserve energy by saying that the initial kinetic energy of the body should be equal to potential energy of the body at the highest point.

This implies that the body would reach the same height with or without the existence of the ramp. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ignoring any dispersive forces, yes. You're right.